# Issue in adding 'com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin:+' plugin in root level in Android Studio Electric Eel - 2022.1.1?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, applovin

Trying to integrate the AppLoving MAX SDK in Android Studio **Electric Eel - 2022.1.1**, but unable to integrate it. Try to add `'com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin:+'` plugin in root level it shows following error

`org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException`

**settings.gradle** file

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://artifacts.applovin.com/android' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "AppLovinMaxSample"
include ':app'
```

Root level **build.gradle** file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.4.0' apply false
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.4' apply false
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.9.2' apply false
    id 'com.applovin.applovin-quality-service' version '+' apply false
}
```

App Level **build.gradle** files

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'applovin-quality-service'
}

applovin {
    apiKey "kdlksi980"
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.applovin:applovin-sdk:11.8.0'
}
```

How add 'com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin:+' pugin in root level in Android Studio Electric Eel - 2022.1.1?

Comment: Try by providing version in this library    id 'com.applovin.applovin-quality-service' version '+' and replace with (plus symbol) +

Comment: @MaveňツTried still faceing the same issue

Comment: in my case `applovin{ apikey = "key"}` not adding so how to add this can you please share

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add the AppLovin SDK to your Android project in the following way.

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.applovin.quality:AppLovinQualityServiceGradlePlugin:4.10.0"
    }
}
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.1' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.1' apply false
}
```